# Remove Default Splash screen in Expo ( React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, splash-screen

We have used React Native Expo for our development but while running the application we are getting a default splash screen other than our custom splash screen.

Can anyone help me to remove the default screen and set our custom splash screen.

Comment: The process of creating a custom splash screen is well explained here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/splash-screens/

Comment: Hey, did u solved this issue? I am also facing the same thing

Comment: @SVG you can remove `expo.splash` section in `app.json` to remove splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

Remove, below code block to eliminate the splash screen.

```
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  ...
}
```

or replace the image value ("./assets/splash.png") in the above code to have your splash screen.
from your app.json
details in
[the official expo page](https://docs.expo.io/guides/splash-screens/)

(Tested in android simulator)

Answer (score 2):

For expo the splash-screen and icon are configured in app.json in project root.

Remove the `expo.splash`  object definition there to get rid of default / customised Splash screen.

However, it is best practice to have a splash screen to any app to perform some background tasks e.g. Font loading, resource loading etc. otherwise OS will have render white screen which is annoying to end user.

Sample configuration with Splash screen -

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "app-name-slug",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash_1.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    }
}
```

Remove the `expo.splash` from here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove splash screen on expo. The only thing you would achieve by removing the `"splash":{ "image":"./assets/splash.png", }` is removing the default image displayed which will leave the splash screen as a blank white screen. Consider just updating the image being rendered on the splash screen

Answer (score -4):

You can first remove expo with the command

```
yarn global remove cli-expo
```

or

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
```

and configure your splash-screen again.